# map keys of abstract classes that are logically similar

Tags: c++, dictionary

Suppose the user uses a library with `kBase` `vBase` classes. The user adds pairs of keys and values of classes that are available to him (he implemented them using the library) - `v` and `k`. In the library, when added, i want keys that are logically similar (have the same string) to be "merged" into a single key.

He're a code sample with what I've tried :

```
//---------------------------LIBRARY.h------------------------//

#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;   

map<kBase*,vector<vBase*>> mapa;

void printMap();
void addToMap(kBase* k1, vBase* v2);

class kBase {
public:
    virtual ~kBase(){}
};

class vBase {
public:
    virtual ~vBase(){}
};

//---------------------------LIBRARY.cpp------------------------//

void printMap()
{
    // Expect 3 keys to be implemented.
    for (auto i : mapa)
        cout << i.first << endl;
}

void addToMap(kBase* k1, vBase* v2)
{
    // Create a k1. if it doesnt exist - vector will be created.
    // Otherwise, the object will be obtained.
    mapa[k1];
    mapa[k1].push_back(v2);
}

//------------------------USER----------------------------//

#include "LIBRARY.h"

// User's implementation.
class k : public kBase {
public:
    k(string inputString)
    {
        kString = inputString;
    }
    ~k(){}

    string kString;
};

class v : public vBase {
public:

    v(string inputString)
    {
        vString = inputString;
    }
    ~v(){}

    string vString;
};

int main()
{
    // User adds keys and values
    addToMap(new k("key1"), new v("value1"));
    addToMap(new k("key1"), new v("value2"));
    addToMap(new k("key1"), new v("value3"));

    addToMap(new k("key2"), new v("value4"));
    addToMap(new k("key2"), new v("value5"));
    addToMap(new k("key2"), new v("value6"));

    addToMap(new k("key3"), new v("value7"));
    addToMap(new k("key3"), new v("value8"));
    addToMap(new k("key3"), new v("value9"));

    printMap();

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, i cant add base class as a key directly. And the library is not aware of the classes that were implemented by the user (that inherit from the classes of the library). But again, how can the library know if objects given are logically similar.

Should i use a different data structure for that purpose?

Comment: Can you add an interface to the base that returns the key string?

Comment: You'll have to do as Kerrek asks, then implement a custom sort function with which to instantiate the `map` template.  You'll find plenty of Q&A here to how to specify a custom sort order for user-defined types.

Comment: but how can i implement a custom sort function, if in the library level i know  nothing about the derived class in the user level? The library is not awared of the strings in the derived classes @TonyD

Comment: @AlexGoft: you can't, that's why Kerrek asked if you could add to the interface, i.e. `virtual const std::string& get_name() const = 0;`.  You can then use it in the custom sort function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ map uses the equivalence concept for finding the entry, which is defined via “less” comparison. Two keys k1 and k2 are considered equivalent if `k1 “is not less than” k2` and `k2 “is not less than” k1`. So all you need is to define the functor for comparing pointers to `kBase` class.

```
class kBaseLessCompare
{
public:
    bool operator() (const kBase * k1, const kBase * k2)
    {
        // something like the following, but you shall define your comparison
        return k1->name < k2->name;
    }
}
```

Then change your map definition to the following:

```
map<const kBase*, vector<vBase*>, kBaseLessComapre> mapa;
```

Comment: why still functor, why not lambda?

Comment: @RichardGeorge You need a *tyoe* to use as the template argument for `std::map`. The type of a lambda is poorly usable for that. And by making it a dedicated functor, you nicely take care of default constructability too.

Comment: Thank you, Eugene! But still, i don't understand - k1 and k2 are *pointers* to *Base class object that don't have the field "name"*. I may add to the code `virtual bool operator<(const kBase &other) const = 0;` and leave it to the user to implement. But still, void `addToMap(kBase* k1, vBase* v2);` is in library level..according to what will be the comparison

Comment: @Alex Goft You need something that will unite your hierarchy. `name` is just an example. For example, in class `kBase` you can define a virtual function `id` that that will be reimplemented in the derived classes. This function will be used by `kBaseLessCompare`